# What's the difference between these two "Get to" vs "Arrive at" in terms of meaning?

Tags: meaning, idioms

What would be your reaction or answer to these declarative statements?

I arrived at the hotel.

I got to the hotel.

Comment: Either is correct - _I arrived at the hotel_ is a more formal way to say it.

Comment: By default, "general-purpose" ***get to*** potentially carries stronger allusions to *[finally] **attained, reached** [after not inconsiderable effort]*. There are other semantic and syntactic differences, but approximately speaking, they "mean" the same thing. Use whichever you like best all the time, and eventually *someone* will point out you've done so in a context where they're *not* interchangeable. But if I were you, I'd cross that bridge when (if! :) you come to it. Just choose a default for now.

Answer (score 0):

Both sentences mean roughly the same thing. The first version (with "arrived at") is somewhat more formal.